# How can I use awk to print a header file and then tab separated values into a csv file?

Tags: awk, sed

I deleted my original question and have to take a different approach.

Now I have an actual tab separated values file:

name->(tab)address->(tab)city->(tab)state etc.

I want to take this file and convert it to csv.

But the top line of the new csv needs actual column names I can enter. ("name", "address", etc.)

How can I do this with csv?

Comment: If the fields are fixed width, use `FIELDWIDTHS`

Comment: Please, post some sample data (in text, not images) with the related expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Fields are all of varying lengths.

Comment: Your expected output is identical as your sample input. You don't need awk to do that ;)

Comment: If I don't use awk to convert it to csv, everything ends up in Column 1 of the CSV file.  That's why awk.

Comment: Your expected output is identical to your sample input though. What do you want awk to do? I assumed that you would want commas in your output, but your desired output suggests you don't. I'm assuming that desired output is a mistake and I've added an answer that I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome @user12733923! I suggest you give [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a read: Right now when the `Sample Input Text` is run through your `awk` command it doesn't produce the `Current Output in CSV` (which isn't even a CSV) so it's very hard to tell exactly what's going wrong (most likely your input doesn't include `<blank>`, but we don't know _how_ it's actually encoded, so can't really help).

Comment: As I am trying to reproduce a proper example I am coming to the realization that the text file is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paraphrasing your question:

> I have a tab-separated file with no header.
>   I want to transform it into comma-separated, adding a header at the same time.

Here's one way (assuming your shell is bash)

```sh
header=(Loc Name Address Apt City State Zip)
(IFS=$'\t'; echo "${header[*]}"; cat file) |
  awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' '{$1 = $1; print}'
```

The `$1 = $1` part is an awk idiom: awk won't recalculate the line using the new field separator unless the data has been updated.

Given this input file

```sh
$ cat -A file
US^IJohn^I742 Evergreen Terr.^I^ISpringfield^IMA^I01101$
US^IJane^I666 5th Avenue^I#1408^INew York^INY^I11101$
```

the command outputs

```
Loc,Name,Address,Apt,City,State,Zip
US,John,742 Evergreen Terr.,,Springfield,MA,01101
US,Jane,666 5th Avenue,#1408,New York,NY,11101
```

Comment: There's more that can be done to ensure the output is valid CSV.

Comment: I have no idea how this answer works but it does.  I am marking it as accepted.  Thank you kind stranger.

Comment: Ask some (specific) questions, you may get answers.